# Unable to filter json data for country,state,city dropdown

Tags: angular

I am developing a country,state,city dependable dropdown where I need to populate state details based on country but I am unable to filter it. Could anyone please help me with this.I am getting the below error

> Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.

```
     onSelectCountry(country_id: number) {
        this.selectedCountry = country_id;
        this.selectedState = 0;
        this.cities = [];
           this.states = this.getStates().filter((item) => {
           return item.country_id === Number(country_id)
        });
    }
    getStates() {
        return this.http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1a72vg").subscribe( 
          response => {}
          );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem : You are trying to return a Subscription, not the actual data and then applying the filter over that (which is very clear from the error shown).

Solution:

Return an Observable from `getStates()` and then subscribe to it within `OnSelectCountry()`. And next step is to apply filter.

```
onSelectCountry(country_id: number) {
        this.selectedCountry = country_id;
        this.selectedState = 0;
        this.cities = [];
           this.getStates().subscribe((states) => {
                this.states = states.filter((item) => {
                    return item.country_id === Number(country_id)
                });
          })
    }

getStates() {
        return this.http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1a72vg");
}
```